# phpmyadmin in xampp not working on windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm getting below error when I type in localhost/phpMyAdmin after starting apache and mysql server in Xampp in Windows 10.

Is there a way I can fix this issue?

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Comment: Can you try with the mysql command-line utility to connect to this MySQL server?

Comment: mysql in Xampp on Windows 10 is not working for me either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Bitnami version of Xampp you will have issues with Windows 10. Download and install an older version from sourceforge.net and it should work. I used version 1.7.3 and so far so good.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but fixed it by replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in the config.inc.php file.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was probably because i had installed bitnami and then later installed xampp. I deleted bitnami, xampp and my temp folder C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp. It worked fine after reinstalation. thats the only way it worked for me