# windows10 v 1607 apache + php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

On my notebook with windows10 I use installation of apache + php + mysql as localhost (easyphp or XAMPP). It worked perfectly untill I have upgraded windows 10 to version 1607. The apache and php is working well but Mysql stopped to work, refusing connection to the server.

Have someone the idea how to solve this problem? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752863/phpmyadmin-in-xampp-not-working-on-windows-10

Comment: After installing Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3194496) problem is solved.