# #1030 - Fehler 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" von Speicher-Engine Aria

Tags: mariadb

I face a very delicate issue, which is far beyond my skills to getting a grip around it. I am working since approx. four weeks at a project. I work with xampp environment (apache, php, phpmyadmin,...) and I do things as I do them for ten years now. And it worked fine, so far!

Then two days ago without doing any coding, the error message

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'XXXX'@'localhost' to database 'XXXX' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\XXXX\scripts\connect2SQL.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\XXXX\scripts\connect2SQL.php(6): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'XXXX', 'XXXX', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\XXXX\scripts\init.php(25): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\XXXX\board.php(3): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\Bullwhip\scripts\connect2SQL.php on line 6

appears. Checking for the database, the problems seems to be originated here. Everything here works fine, but when it comes to the check of the permissions, I cannot even access this site in phpmyadmin. The attempt is followed by

## 1030 - Fehler 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" von Speicher-Engine Aria

I don't have any clue, what could have led to this problem. I really would be happy, if someone out there  could give me a hint.

Thank you.

Frank, Germany

Comment: Hi Frank, it looks like your problem isn't with using phpMyAdmin directly, rather the underlying database (which I presume is MariaDB, but if that's wrong please fix my edit). I've edited your tags to hopefully get you better visibility from people who might be able to help

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765779/mysql-issue-when-creating-a-new-user

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you for you support.

I tried to follow the instructions in the link above. Unfortunately I fail to enter the commands in the command line. I tried directly in the phpmyadmin, where I find also commands like check, checksum and repair. No success. Only messages, that status is ok and so on.

:-(

Regards Frank

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something I have the knowledge to help you through. I hope that someone with the answer shows up for you. It seems to be that a worst-case scenario might involve backing up your database, dropping it, and restoring from backup. There may be a better way, but I imagine that's a brute force solution.

Comment: Hi Isaac, I tried, but no success... I try again.

Comment: see: [phpmyadmin in xampp not working on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752863/phpmyadmin-in-xampp-not-working-on-windows-10)